# Table View Controller doesn't show updated core data values

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, reloaddata, pull-to-refresh

Started from scratch with a TVC and a core data tableview controller.
I've implemented a pull to refresh in viewdidload. The thing is when i update core data using sqllite for example, the data is not updated, even if i call `[self.tableView reloadData];`

My MasterViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

and my MasterViewController.m (from Apple template):

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    // Initialize Refresh Control
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    // Configure Refresh Control
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    // Configure View Controller
    [self setRefreshControl:refreshControl];
}

- (void)refresh:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Refreshing View ...");

    // End Refreshing
    [(UIRefreshControl *)sender endRefreshing];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Thanks for help !!

Comment: Does the line
    NSLog(@"Refreshing View...");
get called? If so, I think we will need your cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod to provide an answer.

Comment: YEs it's called. Forgot to add a fetch in refresh procedure !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any part of your code that updates your data.

The fact that you call "reloadData" on your UITableView won't fetch any new data, it will just call again the datasources protocols calls you implemented (numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath, etc). So when the refresh control is pulled, fetch the new data, then call "reloadData".

Comment: Effectively, i don't see any fetch. Added    `[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];` in refresh procedure works like a charm